# AWS Lambda (.NET web api ) configured to use SignalR can't connect to an S3 web site

Tags: azure, websocket, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-2

```
SignalR doesn't work in this case:
-.NET core Web API hosted on AWS Lambda that configured with SignalR.
-Vue Web site hosted on S3 bucket also configured with SignalR.
Both can't connect on AWS, but they work fine locally on my machine.

I tried to specify the transport type explicitly ( SSE , Long polling)
but in vain.
Error messages I got until now, stuff like the following :

"Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled" 

"Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'"


Would it help trying to deploy to Azure instead of AWS ? as Azure SignalR service might help more than AWS ?
```

Comment: seems to be a problem with the SSL

Comment: I haven't done much investigation with SignalR using the ASP.NET Core bridge on Lambda. I assumed the persistent connection of websockets would be a blocker. Admittedly though I hadn't tried long polling, would you be able to provide a small sample app for me to investigate with Lambda. Feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet.

If you want a more immediate solution for SignalR on AWS I would suggest looking into Fargate in Elastic Container Service. I have been using Fargate for my Blazor experimentation.